# Hashtag and mention using contenteditable in ment.io

Tags: html, angularjs, hashtag, mention

I am making a hashtag and mention using ment.io in angularjs.. I have a problem when using **contenteditable** like wrapping tags with span. See my screenshot:

[image]

Comment: i really need your help.. :(